# Simultaneous output from libspotify

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I'm curious if it's possible to use libspotify to play multiple files at once, through different outputs. I want to be able to play one song through speakers and jump around through other songs on headphones when djing.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If it's only doable with offline files I'm ok with that. I'd even be fine with having two separate processes running libspotify if that's what works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Libspotify will stop the playback of the first track and call the `play_token_lost()` callback.